# Get Shopware 6 collection elements' values, PHP

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I try to get an array of 'names' of elements of a Collection class for a couple of days. I tried all possible ways I used in Shopware 6, but still can't get it at Subscriber:

```php
public function onListingCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties');
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties.group');

        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $filters = $criteria->getExtension('filters');

        if (!$filters instanceof FilterCollection) {
            return;
        }

        $propertyFilter = $filters->get('properties');

        if (!$propertyFilter instanceof Filter || !\is_array($propertyFilter->getValues())) {
            return;
        }

        $currentPropertyOptions = $propertyFilter->getValues();

        $event->getContext()->addExtension('currentPropertyOptionsCriteria', new ArrayEntity($currentPropertyOptions));


        $criteria1 = new Criteria();
        $criteria1->addAssociation('Tags');
        $criteria1->setIds($currentPropertyOption);

        $tags = new TagCollection();
        $options = $this->optionRepository->search($criteria1, $event->getContext())->getEntities();

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $extension = $option->getExtension('myTags');
            
            if (!$extension instanceof TagCollection) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $tags->merge($extension);
        }

        $tagnames = $tags->getElements('myTags');
        // doesn't work $tagnames = $options->getExtension('myTags')->get('names');
        // doesn't work $tagnames = $options->getExtension('myTags')->getValues();
        // etc..

        // test $event->getContext()->addExtension('myTags1', $tags);
        // test $event->getContext()->addExtension('myTagsNames1', new ArrayEntity($tagnames));
```

Here the myTags1 exctension dump:

```
Shopware\Core\System\Tag\TagCollection {#8104 ▼
  #elements: array:10 [▼
    "49aa54d94e394bc2affb5b702d402e42" => Shopware\Core\System\Tag\TagEntity {#12939 ▶}
    "551fcda8a25f47c990d7a795ef251508" => Shopware\Core\System\Tag\TagEntity {#12943 ▶}
    "8c526404df194a88bf72073fea2fdabd" => Shopware\Core\System\Tag\TagEntity {#12947 ▼
      #name: "Name1"
```

Do someone know, how to get an array of names maybe?

Comment: the method is called getElements() (not getValues() IIRC). You perhaps want to map() on the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $extension = $option->getExtension('myTags');
    
    if (!$extension instanceof TagCollection) {
        continue;
    }
    
    $tags->merge($extension);
}

$names = $tags->map(fn (TagEntity $tag) => $tag->getName());
```

Comment: I get null $tags (with/without currentPropertyOptions) using:
```$tags = $options->getExtension('myTags');```

Page won't load, no error message using: 
```$names = $tags->map(fn (TagEntity $tag) => $tag->getName());```

I have spent another evening for the research including map(), can't find a useful example. Can someone give a tip?

Prority is set for events, if it matters:
```public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
            ['onListingCriteria', -200],
        ],
    ];
}```

Comment: Typo. Should be `$option` not `$options`. Don't just copy and paste. You already had a dump of the collection in your question, so you got it right the first time.  The `map` method is just an abstraction of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) btw.

Comment: I added some of your code to the example for reference.